# Display a temporary web page with javascript

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm making a bookmarklet that scrapes a web page and construct a list of URLs that I want to be diplayed instead of the current web page. How to you create a temporary web page and viewing it in the browser?

This is what I've got so far:

```
var urls = myUrlScraper(window.location.pathname);
var tempPage = "<html>" + urls + "</html>";
window.location = tempPageUrl; // How to do this?
```

Comment: You aren't going to be able to construct a page as a JS var and also refresh to it without some kind of storage. You'd need to update the current page DOM.

Comment: This is impossible without a serverside(ish) solution.

Comment: `var w = window.open(''); w.document.write(tempPage);`?

Comment: `javascript:document.write("<html><b>Hello</b></html>");`

Comment: I like the variety of answers, some say its impossible, others give me a one-liner that works ;) Thanks all!

Comment: Yes I agree that my initial comment was in relation to "making" a temporary file which is impossible.  But there are other solutions available which just temporarily display your returned values somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open a new window and write your HTML to it.
Something like:

```
var urls = myUrlScraper(window.location.pathname);
var tempPage = "<html>" + urls + "</html>";

var w = window.open(''); 
w.document.write(tempPage);
```

Answer (score -1):

If urls is *truly* a list of urls in some HTML context you could add a `div` to `<body>` which you then

```
#myDiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Which would cover all your current content, Then you can append your urls or whatever else arbitrary HTML you want into that `div`